# Mac vs Windows: Eigen::Vector3f(0,0,0).normalized()

Tags: c++, macos, eigen

**Why am I seeing different results for this simple 3d vector operation using Eigen on Mac and Windows?**

I wrote some simulation code on my MacBook Pro (macOS 10.12.6) and tested it extensively. As soon as my colleague tried using it on Windows, he had problems. He gave me a specific failing case. It worked for me. As we dug in, **it came down to an attempt to normalize a 3d zero vector, so an attempt to divide by zero. He got (nan, nan, nan) while I got (0, 0, 0)**. In the context where it happened, the zero result was a soft/harmless fail, which is why I had not noticed it in my testing.

Clearly the vector-of-nans is the right answer. I tried it in an Ubuntu build running under Vagrant and got (-nan, -nan, -nan).

**Does anyone know why I get (0, 0, 0) on macOS? I think by default Xcode is using LLVM. The Ubuntu build used clang.**

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same version of Eigen on both systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that you got a newer Eigen version on macOS. The behavior of `normalize()` had been changed some time ago:
https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/12f866a746

There was a discussion about the expected behavior here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=977

Comment: Thanks, that solves the mystery! When I first tried Googling for the answer I got to that [discussion page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=977) but must not have read all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Check your compiler flags. You probably have fast math enabled (`-ffast-math` in gcc). This enables `-ffinite-math-only` (again, gcc) which, and I [quote](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that arguments and results are not NaNs or +-Infs.